# How to specify a method argument must be of certain class

Tags: python

So I have a class like this:

```
 class Encoder(object):

     movie = None

     def __init__(self, movie_instance):
         self.movie = movie_instance

     def encode_profile_hd(self):
         print "profile 1"

     def encode_profile_sd(self):
         print "profile 2"
```

How can I specify the movie_instance argument passed to the constructor must be of Movie class?

I tried:

```
def __init__(self, Movie movie_instance):
```

But that doesn't work. Sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `isinstance` for that.

```
def __init__(self,movie_instance):
    if(not isinstance(movie_instance, Movie)):
         raise ValueError("movie_instance must be an instance of class Movie")
```

This will work for `Movie` instances as well as anything that inherits from `Movie`.

It's worth noting that a lot of people would say that in Python, this idiom should not be used often.  If something looks like a movie, smells like a movie (do movies have a scent?) and plays like a movie, why not just treat it like a movie?  (In other words, try to use the object like a movie and handle the exception that is raised if it doesn't work).

Comment: "It's worth noting that a lot of people would say that in Python, this idiom should not be used often" - as far as I'm concerned it shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers -- You may have a point.  But, Guido included `isinstance` in the language for a reason.  There are probably cases where objects look enough alike to not raise exceptions, but are different enough that it could cause issues.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: The main reason for explicit type checking is to avoid confusing error messages.  Sometimes passing in an argument of a wrong type leads to an error in an unrelated place at a much later time, and in these cases it can be hard to track down where the actual error is.  In my experience, these occasions are rare, though, and can also be a sign of sub-optimal design.

Comment: @mgilson: there are other valid reason to use isinstance. Also since you can override methods on a per-instance basis, even satisfying the isinstance test doesn't mean much wrt/ potential issues.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: yes, I've seen that case sometimes, specially with functions expecting a tuple or list (possibly and in fact quite often of length 1) and being passed a string instead. That's a case where I would used isinstance, but not to raise an exception - just to wrap the string into a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

Python usually relies on [duck-typing](http://docs.python.org//glossary.html#term-duck-typing), and it is considered bad style to artificially restrict the input parameters of your functions as this makes the code less flexible as it could be.  Simply document the requirements clearly, and if the parameters do not conform to the requirements, the code will fail anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically typed language, you can't pre-declare the type of variables as you do in statically typed languages.

Comment: Sorry, I was used to that from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is not `__init__` it's `__new__`. Further note that `__del__` is not a destructor.

Python's philosophy is duck-typing (unless using ABC's), which means everything that can behave as a duck and quacks like duck, could be a duck.

Explicitly type checking is against the data object model, and should be avoided *unless* you have a specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that. What you should do is to document the requirements for your function. This way, somebody can build a different class and use it as argument to your function, as long as it implements required attributes.

An example of this are [iterators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Any object with `__iter__()` or `next()` function can be used as an iterator. An other exemple is [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects). Any object with attributes of a file can be used as a file in parameters of a function. [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) is an example of such object.